# Homeomorphism question

Tags: general-topology

I'm still new to topology, so I'm having some difficulty with this problem. Show that $(0,1)\times S^1$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^2}$\ {$0$}. A formula for the homeomorphism would be nice, but right now, I'm trying to understand what is going on visually. Is this akin to the stereographic projection, except here, we're constructing the bijection from points on the cylinder?

Comment: Try to find a composition $(0,1)×S^1\to\Bbb R_{>0}×S^1\to \Bbb R^2∖\{0\}$ of heomorphisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A homeomorphism $(0,1)\cong\Bbb R_{>0}$ is given by the formula
$$x\mapsto \frac1{1-x}-1$$
This gives rise to a homeomorphism $(0,1)×S^1\cong\Bbb R_{>0}×S^1$. Now
$$(r,z)\mapsto rz$$ is a homeomorphism 
$\Bbb R_{>0}×S^1\cong\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ with inverse
$$x\mapsto(||x||,x/||x||)$$
Intuitively, we a filling the punctured plane with rays emanating from the origin, with one ray going through each point of the unit circle $S^1$.

Comment: If $X$ be the union of axes given by $xy = 0$ in $R^2$. Is it homeomorphic to a line, a circle, a parabola or the rectangular hyperbola $xy = 1$  @Stefan Hamcke

Answer (score 2):

The picture is as follows. The punctured plane $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is homeomorphic to the (open) punctured unit disc $\mathbb{D} \setminus\{0\}$ via a retraction (this is a type of *annulus* or ring). We want to see that this is homeomorphic to a cylinder. Well, the cylinder is the product $S^1 \times (0,1)$. You can think of these copies of $(0,1)$ as being laid in the $z$-axis on the circle, giving a cylinder in three-dimensions. Another way of drawing it is to have the interval $(0,1)$ be a segment through each point on the circle. The collection of all these segments thickens out the circle to an annulus.